# My Mastech MY-64 DMM shows incorrect voltage for specific selected option

Tags: multimeter

My Mastech MY-64 DMM suddenly started showing incorrect voltage on DC 20v option only. When I select dc 200 option it show correct value, even a aaa battery in 2v dc option show correct voltage.

Why is only 20v dc option showing incorrect reading, is there any way to fix this.

P.S. I changed the multimeter battery to a new one, didn't help.

Comment: there may, or may not be a way to fix the problem ... it all depends on what is causing the issue

Comment: Could it be some faulty resistor or capacitor, any troubleshooting directions?, I have not yet open the unit, but I will soon. Before opening wanted to know if it is problem that has known causes.

Comment: When you open it, carefully inspect the range selector switch contacts. Perhaps a good cleaning.

Comment: take pictures before disconnecting or disassembling anything

Comment: @glen_geek, Thanks for your suggestions, I will follow it. and update my findings here

Comment: @jsotola, yes, I generally always do that. Thanks for reminding. In fact my phone gallery is filled with this kinda junk, need to sit and clean it up some day :P.

Comment: @glen_geek, That helped, All I did after opening is used some IPA to clean the rotary selector contacts after unscrewing it from the PCB. I put it back and voila, it works perfectly fine.